# Is it possible to change/update a query string in a URL using PHP?

Tags: php

Is it possible to programatically change the query URL within PHP? I know I can use the `$_GET['something']` function to *get* data from a URL query, but I don't know how to *change* a query string programatically in PHP.

This is an example of what I want to do:

```
//---- index.php ----\\    
$variable = 23;
```

And my URL is: http://example.com/index.php?variable=23

So if I make `$variable = 10` later on in the program (not using headers, and not hard-coded into a link), I want to be able to programatically update the query URL, so that my URL will now read:

http://example.com/index.php?variable=10

Is this even possible, without using forms?

Comment: Most likely you want first solution proposed by @genesis (`header()`). However, if that's not what you want, explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Okay, thanks :)
Yeah I think the header() method is the only possible approach I can take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
header("Location: index.php?variable=10");
```

or do you mean

```
$_GET['variable'] = 10;
```

?

Comment: Can I actually set `$_GET['variable'] = 10` in PHP? Will that update the query URL? From what I know, that doesn't sound possible.

Comment: By "query URL", I mean: http://example.com/index.php?variable=10

Sorry for being unclear!

Comment: @Titus make sure to put `exit;` after `header()`, because with `header()` you're effectively "restarting" your script with different query parameters, and therefore want to finish current run.

Comment: @Titus: the superglobals (_GET/POST/REQUEST/etc...) are basically read only. You can write to those arrays, but the writes won't change the startup-state of the script, and won't affect urls you write later.